# Predicting actual vs. simulated values in ulam?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, bayesian, predict

I'm a first-year graduate student working on an environmental science project in R. I'm trying to look at variability in wind gusts using a few different meteorological parameters, and after building models for each different input variable I've made my first multilevel model. I'm using only two input variables so far, will likely add more. I built my model using the ulam function.

My advisor wants me to come up with a plot that shows my predicted vs. actual standard deviation values for wind_sd, my output parameter. (predicted=from my model, actual= from the raw data) After a bunch of searching, it seems the only guides I could find for this type of plot used an estimated linear regression model lm(), and the predict() function doesn't seem to work with ulam. I tried using extract.samples but that only gave me simulated values for my priors, it looks like.

I tried making an estimated linear regression model anyway but I'm not too happy with it since it doesn't make any predictions for gusts above 1.5 standard deviations, while the cutoff I'm looking at for my MASSIVE dataset (samples for every hour over the past 35 years) is 5 standard deviations, and there are many hours with brief gusts high above the hourly average wind speed.

So, to be able to make the plot he wants I need to extract the ulam-simulated wind_sd values to plot against the actual sd values. I used a normal distribution- do I need binomial for this? If not, how could I extract the values for my output parameter (wind_sd) or otherwise make the plot?

The code I used to make the ulam model and the linear plot is below. wind_sd is the standard deviation of hourly wind speed (using this to measure variation in wind gusts), t_2m is temperature 2 meters above the surface, and wind_spd is the mean wind speed of that hour.

```
dat_slim_MR <- list(
  wind_sd = new_combined_cc$wind_sd.x,
  t_2m = new_combined_cc$t_2m,
  wind_spd = new_combined_cc$wind_spd
)
str(dat_slim_MR)
dat_slim_MR_df <- as_tibble(dat_slim_MR)
dat_slim_MR_df <- dat_slim_MR_df %>% drop_na(wind_spd)

#1 chain to debug

mgustyMR <- ulam(
  alist(
    wind_sd ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) ,
    mu <- a + b1 * wind_spd + b2 * t_2m,
    a ~ dnorm(0.5, 0.5),
    b1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.02),
    b2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.05),
    sigma ~ dexp(1)
  ) , data=dat_slim_MR_df, chains =1 )

#4 chains for accuracy

mgustyMR_4chains <- ulam(
  alist(
    wind_sd ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) ,
    mu <- a + b1 * wind_spd + b2 * t_2m,
    a ~ dnorm(0.5, 0.5),
    b1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.02),
    b2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.05),
    sigma ~ dexp(1)
  ) , data=dat_slim_MR_df, chains =4, cores=4, iter=1000 )

$tried to extract samples but only gave values for priors...

postmgustyMR4chains <- extract.samples( mgustyMR_4chains ,  clean = FALSE)
str(postmgustyMR4chains)

#this isn't for the model I've made in ulam... it's A model but I want to use the model with the Bayesian priors

my_mod <- lm(wind_sd ~ wind_spd + t_2m, data = dat_slim_MR_df)
plot(x=predict(my_mod), y=dat_slim_MR_df$wind_sd,
     xlab='Predicted Values',
     ylab='Actual Values',
     xlim = c(0,5),
     ylim = c(0,5),
     main='Predicted vs. Actual Values')
abline(a = 0,
       b = 1,
       col = "red",
       lwd = 2)
```

I tried to use ulam to make a similar plot to the one produced by the lm() model, but can't find any sort of function that helps me. How can I plot simulated wind_sd values from mgustyMR_4chains against the original wind_sd values from the dataset?

Comment: There might be useful stuff in the `tidybayes` package ...

Comment: @ben-bolker I think this pointed me to the right direction! The guide here http://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/ has a bullet about "Extracting tidy fits and predictions from models." I think this is what I'm looking for, just using tidybayes.rethinking instead since I'm in ulam. It lists a bunch of different functions, but the descriptions didn't make sense to me at all. How do I know which one will help me simulate wind_sd values? It also linked me to a "see this for more details" but it uses a brms model as an example and I don't really know how to translate that to ulam.

Comment: ulam is most likely returning something like an `rstan` model, which should be supported by tidybayes: http://127.0.0.1:24885/library/tidybayes/doc/tidybayes.html#supported-model-types . As long as you know the names of the parameters you want to extract posterior samples for I think you should be able to do it ...   any chance you can give us a super-simple [mcve] model in ulam that we can play with?

Comment: @ben-bolker Yes, ulam is essentially a slimmed-down rstan. I'm thinking posterior_epred is what I want to use, but running get_variables on my model doesn't tell me that wind_sd can be extracted. I'll look at creating a minimal reproducible example and get back to you. Thanks so much for your help-- I'm a beginner and my advisor is away on vacation, which is why I'm here instead of reaching out to them, LOL!

Comment: Never mind! I got what I needed using the add_predicted_draws function in the rethinking package! Thanks so much! For anyone with this issue in the future, the usage guide to the function I used is here: https://rdrr.io/github/mjskay/tidybayes.rethinking/man/predicted_draws.ulam.html

Comment: Please write up your own answer to this question ... this is allowed and indeed encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Update: the function I was looking for to answer this question was predicted_draws. Here is the code I used.

```
  mgustyMR_predicteddraws <- predicted_draws(
  mgustyMR_4chains,
  dat_slim_MR_df,
  value = ".prediction",
  ndraws = 5)

plot (wind_sd ~ .prediction , mgustyMR_predicteddraws , col=col.alpha(rangi2,0.5),
  xlab='Predicted Values',
  ylab='Actual Values',
  main='Predicted vs. Actual wind_sd values for Bayesian Model')
```